# Factoring quadratic expression $25t^2-16r^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When I factor this quadratic $25t^2-16r^2$ expression I get the following:

$$25t^2-16r^2 = 25t^2 + 20t - 20t + 16r^2 = 5t(5t-4) + 4(5t-4r^2)$$

But the $(5t-4)$ and $(5t-4r^2)$ aren't identical, because of the $r^2$? Can it be factored and how? I changed the $-20t + 20t \ $ to $-20r + 20r$, but the result is completely wrong.

Comment: Would $a^2-b^2=(a+b)\times(a-b)$ be of some help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$25t^{2}-16r^{2}=((5t)^{2}-(4r)^{2})=(5t-4r)(5t+4r)$

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have messed up somewhere.I can show you easy way to find the factors of it.
Treat it as a quadratic of $t$. We know $ax^2+bx+c =a(x-\alpha).(x-\beta)$ ,where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of the equation.
Solving the equation we get, $25t^2 -16r^2= 0 \implies t= \pm \frac{4r}{5}$
So we get,  $25t^2 -16r^2=25 \left(t-\frac{4r}{5}\right).\left(t+\frac{4r}{5}\right)=(5t-4r)(5t+4r).$